# For which $f \in L^2([0,1])$ is $f^\perp \cap C^\infty$ dense in $f^\perp$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given $f \in L^2([0,1])$, $f \neq 0$, we can consider the orthogonal complement $f^\perp$ . The smooth functions $C^\infty([0,1])$ are dense in $L^2([0,1])$. Is the intersection $f^\perp \cap C^\infty([0,1])$ dense in $f^\perp$? If not, can we find a counterexample, and find conditions on $f$ such that the statement is true?

The following [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108496/dense-subset-of-l2-mathbb-r) generalizes to show that the statement holds for any smooth, strictly positive function.

In general the problem amounts to showing that for any $g \in f^\perp$ there exists a sequence of smooth functions $g_n \in f^\perp$ such that $||g-g_n|| \to 0$. I've tried using the Fourier basis, to move the problem into $\ell^2$, and construct $g_n$ as a finite sequence (to guarantee smoothness) with the proposed properties. My attempts so far:

Let $\{ \phi_k \}$ denote the Fourier basis of $L^2([0,1])$, such that $f = \sum_{k} c_k \phi_k$, and $g = \sum_k d_k \phi_k$, where $g \in f^\perp$. Define $g_n = \sum_{k = - n}^n d_k^n \phi_k$ for some coefficients $d_k^n$, then $g_n$ is smooth. Choose the coeffients as
$$
d_k^n = \begin{cases}
0, & |k| > n \\
d_k, & c_k = 0, |k| \leq n \\
d_k - \frac{\sum_{|j| \leq n} c_j d_j}{(2n+1) c_k},& c_k \neq 0, |k| \leq n
\end{cases}
$$

A direct calculation show that $g_n \in f^\perp$. Showing that $g_n \to g$ amounts to show that the fraction in the definition of the coefficients goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. The numerator goes to zero since $\langle g,f \rangle = 0$. The problem is that $c_k \to 0$, so I have to estimate the fraction by something which goes to zero, and for this I have been unsuccesful. Could the approach be modified to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f^\perp\cap C^\infty([0,1])$ is dense in $f^\perp$.

Indeed, given a closed finite codimensional subspace $M$ of a normed space $X$ and a dense subspace $V$ of $X$, the intersection $V\cap M$ is dense in $M$. 
See IV.2.8 Lemma in S. Goldberg "Unbounded linear operators". McGraw-Hill, 1966.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I understand something wrong but here is a proposal:
Let $f_n$ and $g_n$ be sequences of smooth functions converging to $f$ resp. $g \in f^\perp$. Now define $h_n=g_n-\frac{\langle f,g_n \rangle}{\langle f,f_n \rangle}f_n$. Obviously $h_n \in f^\perp$ and $h_n$ smooth. We have
$$\|h_n-g\|\leq \|g_n-g\|+\frac{|\langle f,g_n \rangle|}{|\langle f,f_n \rangle|}\|f_n\|.$$
Now notice that $\|g_n-g\|\rightarrow 0$, $\langle f,g_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle f,g \rangle=0$, $\langle f,f_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle f,f \rangle>0$ and $\|f_n\|\rightarrow \|f\|$. Hence the RHS (and therefore also the LHS) converges to zero.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. I suspected it being quite simple, but the construction evaded me. Thanks.